# Parsing html with "unclosed tags" in java

Tags: java, html, parsing

My Question is quite simple: 
is there a way to parse html in java to a DOM-Document, if there are tags like this img-tag in the htmlcontent?

```
<p><img src="..."></p>
```

This is the Codesnippet that gives me a SAXException while parsing these elements:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( htmlcontent.getBytes());
Document dom = db.parse(is);
is.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so but [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) can do that. It's not the DOM API but it's quite similar.

Comment: Feel free to approve the answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `DocumentBuilder` because it is an XML parser.

But you need an HTML parser like:

- [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html)
- [Neko HTML Parser](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

One of these may help:

- http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/
- http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/

Answer (score 0):

HTML isn't XML.

Except when you're using XHTML.

So there is no reason an XML parser should parse your HTML.

Use a HTML parser like [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/).